# python dataframe gropuby using pd.Series.mode throws error when `by` column contains values with same starting value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.6, pandas-groupby, mode

I have a dataframe as follows.

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Name" : ['Thomas', 'Thomas', 'Thomas John'],
    "Credit" : [1200, 1300, 900],
    "Mood" : ['sad', 'happy', 'happy']
})
```

I am trying to group it as follows.

```py
aggrFDColumnDetails = {
   'Mood':pd.Series.mode,
   'Credit':'sum'
}
df2.groupby(['Name']).agg(aggrFDColumnDetails)
```

But it throws the following error

```
Exception: Must produce aggregated value
.....
....
and a lot of stack traces..
```

If I change the third name to `John` instead of `Thomas John`, it works as expected.
Could anyone help me to solve it ?

**Analysis - 1**
If I change the dataframe as follows, it works

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Name" : ['Thomas John', 'Thomas John', 'Thomas'],
    "Credit" : [1200, 1300, 900],
    "Mood" : ['sad', 'happy', 'happy']
})
```

If the value starts with previous rows value, then it throws error

Comment: maybe use `lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0]` instead of `pd.Series.mode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use:

```
aggrFDColumnDetails = {
   'Mood':lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax(),
   'Credit':'sum'
}
df=df2.groupby(['Name']).agg(aggrFDColumnDetails)
print(df)

              Mood  Credit
Name                      
Thomas       happy    2500
Thomas John  happy     900
```

---

as [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) sort in descending order we could also use:

```
aggrFDColumnDetails = {
   'Mood':lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0],
   'Credit':'sum'
}
```